# Split New Line - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, split, newline

Would appreciate any help on this problem

In MS Access

I'd like to split the values of one field (Main Address) to 2 separate fields (Address 1 and Address 2) where in Address 1 gets the first line and then Address 2 gets the second and other line items

ex #1

```
Main Address   |  Address 1  | Address 2
----------------------------------------
1 Main Road    | 1 Main Road | San Jose CA               
San Jose CA
```

ex #2

```
Main Address   |  Address 1  | Address 2
----------------------------------------
1 Main Road    | 1 Main Road | San Jose CA Drop at Front   
San Jose CA    
Drop at Front
```

Thanks All!

Hope the representation of the samples makes sense, if not let me know if you have questions and I'll clarify! TA

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's not clear from your question whether you wish to create a query which displays a split version of the Main Address field, whether you wish to update the original table with these new columns or whether you intend something else entirely. Either way I feel this is bordering on a 'write my code for me' question rather than a question with a specific correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [Main Address] data have Cr and Lf characters to force new lines? If it doesn't, what you want is virtually impossible. If yes, an expression in query or textbox:

`Replace(Left([Main Address] & "", Instr([Main Address] & Chr(13), Chr(13))), Chr(13), "")`

`Trim(Replace(Mid([Main Address] & "", Instr([Main Address] & Chr(13), Chr(13))), Chr(13) & Chr(10), " "))`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the split works well if the MAIN address has 2 or more lines. However I'm getting a #Func! error when there's only 1 line on the Main Address. Any suggestions? :) Thanks again!

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot June! Address 1 looks perfect and Address 2 is OK but whenever Address 2 has a value on it, there's this New Line before the text, but when the Address 2 has No Value, it looks perfect and doesn't contain anything on it. 

Mind if you edit the Address 2 a bit more :) TA!

Comment: Okay, see revised answer again.